# Ckeditor: how to avoid html tags in ckeditor on save time in mysql

Tags: javascript, php

I am using ckeditor for my small web project(am using yii Framework), but when I edit a content or create a new content, it automatically add Html tags and save time also html tags automatically saved in mysql DB also.  how to stored without HTML tags?  how do I remove it?

EX: in CKeditor input:  `welcome`

in DB Output: `<p>welcome</p>`

i want to remove html tags on storing time in DB.

this s my code

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'template_email', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
     <div class="controls"> 

<?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'template_email', array('rows' => 6, 'cols' => 50, 'id'=>'editor1')); ?> 

    </div>
 </div>
```

Script

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function actionCreate()

{ if(isset($_POST['CrmSettings']))

{$model->attributes=$_POST['CrmSettings'];

if($model->save())

$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));

}
}

}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strip_tags()` at the time of inserting data in table.

You can see the documentation  at [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: @user3093894 that's a native php function, just wrap it around the variable holding your value

Comment: the code you have putted above doesn't seems to be helpful. Write the model where you execute the insert query.

Comment: Any other options ther ?

Comment: @user3093894: that's the only easy and clean solution